# Is the kids moon disease a skin cancer?

Tags: dermatology, cancer

Dry pigmented skin or kids moon

Xeroderma pigmentosum is a genetic disease that was first discovered in 1870 by Dr. Moritz Kaposi, a product of the loss of oxygen-deficient ribosome DNA, in its treatment of mutations caused by UV penetrating of the skin. Due to the absence of the DNA polymerase 1 and 3, which causes the burning of the skin and its full ulcer and the inevitable infection of cancer.

Comment: Are you asking if xeroderma pigmentosum is cancer? If so, the answer is no, but it's not clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, why no Though the xeroderma pigmentosum becomes a skin cancer ,